# Connect to a Router via Terminal

Tags: router, debian, ethernet

How can i connect to a router **via** the **CLI** (eth or wlan) and 
login with the password i created? My OS is based on Debian.
So if you have no GUI with suggestions that show you the available Networks (routers).

Comment: Let me clarify, you wanted to connect from your PC to your router via command line? 
Does your router allows incoming telnet / SSH connection? (most routers only allow GUI / web based administration)
And assuming that it does, all you need is just check what is the 'gateway' IP as it is often the router by either using ifconfig (linux) or ipconfig (windows). 
What are you trying to do anyway? Can you clarify?

Comment: Under Ubuntu is for example a program "Network connections" where can add your PC to new networks and login with the Wlan-password. And my question is if there is an tool for the CLI to do this?

Comment: @Darius, FYI, I came here from Google with the same question as the OP, and your comment that "most routers only allow GUI/web based administration" was sufficient answer for me.  So thanks.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like SSH or Telnet to connect to the router, make sure it the ports for the specific tool are open if the router supports remote configuration in that way.